# how can i get the latest payment date on second table?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

**This is my current query**

$sql = "SELECT `full_name`, `amount`, 
                 SUM(`payments`.`payment_amount`) as `totalPayment`, 
                 `borrowers`.`amount` - SUM(`payments`.`payment_amount`) as `totalBalance`,
                 `date_borrowed`,`borrowers`.`id`
                 FROM `borrowers` 
                  LEFT JOIN `payments` ON `borrowers`.`id`= `payments`.`borrower_id` 
                  GROUP BY `borrowers`.`id` ORDER BY `date_borrowed` DESC";

---

first table;[image]

second table;
[image]

My table; 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The join will give you all payment records, you only want the last one. Make a subquery:

```
$sql = "SELECT 
   full_name, amount, SUM(payments.payment_amount) as totalPayment,
   borrowers.amount - SUM(payments.payment_amount) as totalBalance, 
   date_borrowed, borrowers.id,
   (SELECT payment_date FROM payments 
       WHERE borrowers.id=payments.borrower_id 
       ORDER BY payment_date DESC LIMIT 0,1) 
       AS last_payment
    FROM borrowers GROUP BY borrowers.id ORDER BY date_borrowed DESC";
```